# Schoology API OAuth 1.0 throwing 404 error while calling auth/authorize endpoint

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am using schooly API which follows OAuth 1.0 and following this documentation: https://developers.schoology.com/api-documentation/authentication#toc-item-3

I am able to get request token using this endpoint: https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/request_token

But when I try to call authorize API: https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/authorize, I am getting error 404 Not found.

Answer (score 1):

The default auth url is this: `https://www.schoology.com/oauth/authorize`.

If the user is in a district with its own schoology url like `cityschool.schoology.com` then you would use an auth url like this: `https://cityschool.schoology.com/oauth/authorize`.

I found this out by examining the source code of their PHP library here: https://github.com/schoology/schoology_php_sdk/blob/master/SchoologyApi.class.php#L365